# linux and assembly - blocking

Tags: linux, blocking, assembly

does Linux block ports and interrupts for user programs use ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only interrupt a non-kernel program should be using is int 0x80, which is the interrupt to request one of the system calls listed in /usr/include/sys/syscall.h. If you want to directly interact with hardware interrupts, this should be done inside a kernel module. [A good introduction to Assembly on a Linux system](http://asm.sourceforge.net/articles/linasm.html). [This thread should also be useful for you](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/bios-interrupt-in-linux-assembly-669794/).

Comment: As noted in the LinuxQuestions thread I linked to, a program like http://www.dosbox.com/ or http://www.dosemu.org/ will do the same interrupt emulation that windows provides for assembly programs (even with windows you are not really using interrupts, but getting pseudo-interrupts though an emulator).